# PHPUnit Mock RequestStack of symfony

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I don't understand how mock this : `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getContent()`

there are 2 methods : `getCurrentRequest()->getContent()` and it return a json object (POST Response)

I use symfony with `RequestStack` class.

The entire code is

```
class MessageReceivedService
{
    protected $message;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->message = json_decode($requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getContent());
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do work in your constructor. This is a bad thing, it is better to delay this until the information is really needed. That way you only spend time for things that really need to be done.

Comment: Thanks @Sven for your expertise, so for you I should use setter and not constructor ? The methods in this service don't work if I don't have the json response of the Api. Thanks

Comment: In that case you could create a method `parseResponse` which is called before any other method is executed (in the methods themselves) and caches the returned value.

Comment: Thanks, Could you give me a example ? If I understand, I create one method who called in first in each method of my service ? Or I must create event system ? Thanks

Comment: You are passing the $requestStack. Store it. Only start decoding the json from it when getMessage is called. It basically is shifting the work from the constructor to the method that needs the info that is not created in the constructor anymore. If more than one place needs that info, create a private function that returns the data (and maybe stores it if re-creating it is expensive).

Comment: Thank you very much Sven and Ramon-kleiss

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't actually have to mock the `RequestStack` class, since it's basically a container.

If you want to test with the `RequestStack`, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MessageReceivedServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        $request = new Request([], [], [], [], [], [], [], json_encode([
            'foo' => 'bar'
        ]));

        $requestStack = new RequestStack();
        $requestStack->push($request);

        // Do your tests
    }
}
```

When you call `currentRequest` on the `$requestStack` variable, it should return the `$request` variable.

Comment: Thanks but, normally in unit test, we don't have to use new Class(), no ?

Comment: I usually only really mock things that I can't really test (fast, which is a requirement for unit tests). For example: database queries, network requests or classes with a lot of other dependencies. For a simple container class like `RequestStack`, I'd just use the actual class since it does nothing really exciting.